# House number parameter in cloudmade doesn't work

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, cloudmade

I've problem with the `house` Parameter of the cloudmade geocoding API.
i.e. I'am looking for house number 10 in the German City Gießen:

```
http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/geocoding/v2/find.html?query=zipcode:35390;city:giessen;house:10;street:bahnhofstrasse;country:Germany&return_geometry=true&results=1
```

cloudmade finds the correct street, but number 10 is not in the middle of the street. I've the same problem with all streets.

The API documentation sais I am right: http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/geocoding-http-api#Structured-search

Answer (score 1):

They seem to ignore the *house* key and just return the same result as if it hasn't been provided. But searching on http://maps.cloudmade.com/ returns the same vague result. While [the data you are searching for](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/way/162237024) is in OSM's data base it might not be in CloudMade's data base for whatever reason. Therefore I guess this is a problem with CloudMade's geocoding database and not a problem of their API.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are no house number data in our data set, so we return only street. Also in couple of months we'll launch new geocoding with more detailed data.

Comment: In that case (even in all other tests) there was a house number included. Maybe I've made a mistake. Is my URL syntax correct?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. And problem is in our data. We know about this, and we'll fix this ASAP

Comment: @Cloudmade is there a date for that?